# rvalue qualified method and const expression

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, constexpr

How can I make a const rvalue in a natural way?

Here is a simple example :

```
struct A {
  void f() &&{}                 // 1
  constexpr bool f() const &{return true;}  // 2
  constexpr bool f() const &&{return true;} // 3 really usefull?
};

int main() {
    static_assert(A{}.f()); // does not compile because call 1 instead of 3
    constexpr A a;
    static_assert(a.f());
}
```

Why does the first `static_assert()` call 1 instead of 3?

Comment: What's the question, exactly?

Comment: Are you asking how to declare a `const rvalue`?

Comment: sorry but... you're checking `static_assert()`s with `constexpr` returning `void` ?

Comment: The question is, how can I make rvalue object works on a const expression

Comment: @max66 it is a simple question, maybe the static_assert is not useful here

Comment: I add one minimalist example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is `A{}` doesn't give you a `const A`, it just gives you an `A` so 2 gets called since it is callable on a non const rvalue.

If you want 4 to be called you need to make a `const A` and you can do that using an alias declaration.  If you have `using A_const = const A;` then `A_const{}` gives you a `const A` and `A_const{}.f()` will call 4 instead of 2.

Essentially what it does is `static_assert(const A{}.f());`, but since syntactically you can't write it that way we need to using declaration to give us a single word type that is a `const A`.

---

Additionally you could rewrite

```
static_assert(A{}.f());
```

as

```
static_assert(std::add_const_t<A>{}.f());
```

and also get a `const A` rvalue.

Comment: So there is no way to write it in a natural way?

Comment: @AntoineMorrier No, The C++ syntax does not allow you to write `static_assert(const A{}.f());`

Comment: So note: This is not a language limitation, it's a parsing limitation. You can solve it using an alias.

Comment: I think I should try to not use ref qualified methods, making an alias is not a good solution for me :). Thanks ;)

Comment: @AntoineMorrier You can also cast your `A{}` into a `const A` to force the const onto the value. a `const &&` method is generally not very useful though because there is basically no context where it would get involved unless you manually apply the necessary force…

Comment: Actually i am doing a kind of "easier to use" tuple. So i wanted to try `my_tuple{5}.get(0_n) == 5;` ^^. That is why I wanted such a thing

Comment: @AntoineMorrier Why do you even need to overload based on reference qualification for that?

Comment: Because when I call get on a rvalue object, I want attributes get moved. However the answer of Richard makes me think about it. Since I am using template and constexpr apply on constexpr object, there is no issues about using constexpr rvalue qualified method

Comment: @AntoineMorrier Just remember you can't move something that is `const`/`constexpr` so having `const &&` is basically useless.

Answer (score 2):

> The question is, how can I make rvalue object works on a const expression

Another way can be through a `constexpr` function returning an `A const`

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
 {
   std::size_t f() & { return 1u; }
   std::size_t f() && { return 2u; }
   constexpr std::size_t f() const & {return 3u; }
   constexpr std::size_t f() const && {return 4u; } 
 };

constexpr A const foo ()
 { return {}; }

int main()
 {
   static_assert( foo().f() == 4u, "!" );      
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this does what you want?

```
struct A {
    constexpr bool f() &&{return true;}                 // 1
    constexpr bool f() const &{return true;}  // 2
    constexpr bool f() const &&{return true;} // 3 really usefull?
};

int main() {
    static_assert(A{}.f()); // does not compile because call 1 instead of 3
    constexpr A a;
    static_assert(a.f());
}
```

Comment: No, because in your case, A{}.f still call 1, that is not constexpr. However, it could be good for my use, because making constexpr f() && is not that absurd since I am dealing with template. So thanks

Comment: @AntoineMorrier - well... (1) **is** `constexpr`. I suppose doesn't works in C++11 (where a `constexpr` method is automatically also `const`) but should works in C++14 and C++17.

Comment: Thanks for the information :). It works perfectly well. I remember have seen an article where it was explained that constexpr does not mean const method in C++14 yes. Thanks for the remaining :)